# Arduino SD library arduino-core 1:1.0.0.1+dfsg-7 undefined reference

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, arduino

I'm trying to compile the [DumpFile example](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DumpFile) on Raspbian using the arduino-core and arduino-mk packages.

It usually worked well for other projects, but when it comes to using the SD library I have errors at compilation time, I don't know if it's something I do wrong or if it's an issue in the SD library itself.

From the [changelog of the arduino-core](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/a/arduino/arduino_1.0.5+dfsg2-1_changelog) package, there are nothing that was fixed in the SD library between my version of the package and the most recent one. So upgrading may not help.

I'm copying the output of running >make

```
/usr/bin/avr-gcc -c -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=100 -I. 
-I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD -I/home/pi/sketchbook/libraries/SD -g -Os -w -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions /usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/File.cpp -o build-cli/libs/SD/File.o
mkdir -p build-cli/libs/SD/
/usr/bin/avr-gcc -c -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=100 -I. -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD -I/home/pi/sketchbook/libraries/SD -g -Os -w -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions /usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/SD.cpp -o build-cli/libs/SD/SD.o
/usr/bin/avr-ar rcs build-cli/libcore.a  build-cli/WInterrupts.o  build-cli/wiring_analog.o  build-cli/wiring.o  build-cli/wiring_digital.o  build-cli/wiring_pulse.o  build-cli/wiring_shift.o  build-cli/CDC.o  build-cli/HardwareSerial.o  build-cli/HID.o  build-cli/IPAddress.o  build-cli/main.o  build-cli/new.o  build-cli/Print.o  build-cli/Stream.o  build-cli/Tone.o  build-cli/USBCore.o  build-cli/WMath.o  build-cli/WString.o  build-cli/libs/SD/File.o build-cli/libs/SD/SD.o
/usr/bin/avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p -Wl,--gc-sections -Os -o build-cli/readSd.elf build-cli/readSd.o build-cli/libcore.a  -lc -lm
build-cli/libcore.a(File.o): In function `File::operator bool()':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/File.cpp:146: undefined reference to `SdFile::sync()'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/File.cpp:148: undefined reference to `SdFile::write(void const*, unsigned int)'
build-cli/libcore.a(File.o): In function `File::operator bool()':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:214: undefined reference to `SdFile::read(void*, unsigned int)'
build-cli/libcore.a(File.o): In function `File::operator bool()':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/File.cpp:149: undefined reference to `SdFile::seekSet(unsigned long)'
build-cli/libcore.a(File.o): In function `File::operator bool()':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:214: undefined reference to `SdFile::close()'
build-cli/libcore.a(SD.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z20getNextPathComponentPcPjS_':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/Sd2Card.h:155: undefined reference to `Sd2Card::init(unsigned char, unsigned char)'
build-cli/libcore.a(SD.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z20getNextPathComponentPcPjS_':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:430: undefined reference to `SdVolume::init(Sd2Card*, unsigned char)'
build-cli/libcore.a(SD.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z20getNextPathComponentPcPjS_':
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:43: undefined reference to `SdFile::openRoot(SdVolume*)'
build-cli/libcore.a(SD.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z20getNextPathComponentPcPjS_':
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `SdVolume::init(Sd2Card*, unsigned char)'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:430: undefined reference to `vtable for SdFile'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:430: undefined reference to `vtable for SdFile'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `vtable for SdFile'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `vtable for SdFile'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `SdFile::close()'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `SdFile::open(SdFile*, char const*, unsigned char)'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `vtable for SdFile'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `vtable for SdFile'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `SdFile::close()'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `vtable for SdFile'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `vtable for SdFile'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `SdFile::open(SdFile*, char const*, unsigned char)'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `SdFile::open(SdFile*, char const*, unsigned char)'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `SdFile::close()'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `SdFile::seekSet(unsigned long)'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `vtable for SdFile'
/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility/SdFat.h:138: undefined reference to `vtable for SdFile'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build-cli/readSd.elf] Error 1
```

Could someone please help me to pinpoint at the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the SD library has a sub directory containing the functions that are undefined. Perhaps you need to add -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SD/utility to your make

Comment: Thanks, you are right, in the makefile I should specify the SD folder and subfolders too like this:

      ARDUINO_LIBS = SD SD/utility